# azure mobile app quick start sample apps don't display result

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I created about 6 different azure mobile app using visual studio and from portal website but none of them worked.  I tried this several months ago and remember being worked but not last week.

All I am doing is create azure mobile app not mobile service and use default TodoItem data.  It displays data when I put /tables/TodoItem on the url but when I download the quick start app using ios or xamarin it doesn't work.  I can't figure out what the issue is.  Error doesn't much make sense either.  Sorry I don't have the debug error message right now from ios.

Thanks

Comment: Wil, If you have a chance to grab the error details, that will really help identify what might be going on. Can you update the question with any error information you may have when you have a chance?

Comment: I did exactly same way as last 8 times but this time used a different Resource Group and it worked.  What a pain this was.. and I still don't know why it worked.  thanks anyway

Comment: Hi Wil, would you please either remove the question or answer it yourself? Thanks :)